# How do I increase the distance of Label from bar/column in MS Chart using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I have set the label outside the bar/column, but I want to move a little bit more so that it does not touch the edge of the bar/column.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

add `CssClass="CssClassName"` to this label and and write in the css `.CssClassName{margin-left/right:10px;}`

it's the easiest way to make this